# Should getters from domain classes not be prefixed with "get" in DDD, and why?

Tags: java, oop, domain-driven-design, naming-conventions

The [DDDSample project](http://dddsample.sourceforge.net/), now hosted in a [Github repository](https://github.com/citerus/dddsample-core), seems to be a reference about how to design a DDD project.

I noticed all the getters in the domain classes are not prefixed by `get` (ex: `Cargo#delivery`) while they are prefixed in the classes outside of the domain package (ex: `HandlingEventRegistrationAttempt#getTrackingId`).

Richard C. Martin, in his book Clean Code, sates:

> Accessors, mutators, and predicates should be named for their value and prefixed with get, set, and is according to the javabean standard.

So, should we avoid to follow his advice in this context? If so, why would it be more important than consistency?

Comment: If you do not have pair set method to "getter-like" method, then get prefix is useless - shorter name with the same meaining is always cleaner thus better. Someone may argue that "get" is usefull for code completition, but in result it would make lines in your code longer (worse?).

Comment: Downvoter: at least explain why, as it is a common courtesy here...

Comment: The Q's title suggests that you're seeing this codebase as gospel truth, including for small unimportant details such as accessor prefixes. I think caution would have you at least rename it to something like *Should getters from domain classes not be prefixed with "get" in DDD, and why?*

Comment: I updated the title, I didn't see this subtlety in English, thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why getters from domain classes should not be prefixed with “get” in DDD?

The easy place to start from is *mutators*; note the immediately previous sentence in *Clean Code*

> Mutators should have verbs or verb phrase names like *postPayment*, *deletePage*, or *save*.

This idea is consistent with the principle that the domain model should not be anemic, and that the language of the domain should be *ubiquitous*: we should be seeing the same language in the code that our domain experts use when explaining the business.

That's why you aren't going to see `set` very often, unless that verb happens to have significance in your domain.

Accessors and predicates are both examples of *queries*.  As understood by [Bertrand Meyer](http://se.ethz.ch/~meyer/publications/online/eiffel/basic.html), queries give information about an instance without modifying the instance, and they satisfy the *uniform access principle*

> from the outside, whether a query is an attribute (field in each object) or a function (algorithm) should not make any difference. For example a_vehicle.speed could be an attribute, accessed from the object's representation; or it could be computed by a function that divides distance by time. The notation is the same in both cases, so that it's easy to change representation without affecting the rest of the software.

So, how should these be named?

Vaughn Vernon, in [Implementing Domain-Driven Design](https://books.google.com/books?id=X7DpD5g3VP8C&lpg=PA246&ots=tSzJEGBeVN&dq=domain%20driven%20design%20javabean&pg=PA245#v=onepage&q=domain%20driven%20design%20javabean&f=false), writes

> The method names of Side-Effect-Free Functions are important.  Although these methods all return Values (because they are CQS query methods) they purposely avoid the use of the get-prefix JavaBean naming convention.  This simple but effective approach to object design keeps the Value Object faithful to the Ubiquitous Language.  The use of getValuePercentage() is a technical computer statement, but valuePercentage() is a fluent human-readable language expression.

Steven Lowe writes

> Developers tend to think and talk in development terms, which naturally results in inadvertent models of how instead of what and why. This is common, and it's a tar pit, because developers tend to follow established patterns. What's more, once the true purpose of the code is obscured, it's unlikely that anyone will unearth it.

I would express the idea this way: domain experts should be able to read the code in the domain model, and evaluate its correctness.  That means that the domain code should not have embedded within it artifacts related to infrastructure.

Robert Martin's spelling of this idea?

> Reader's shouldn't have to mentally translate your names into other names they know.

(Martin later asserts that terms should be taken from the solution domain, from the premise that most of the readers will be programmers, rather than domain experts.  The DDD counter argument would be that programmers should be acquiring domain expertise as they model the business.)

Comment: So, according to Vaughn Vernon, we should use `valuePercentage()` to be  faithful to the Ubiquitous Language. Should this rule apply to the domain package only or to the whole project to keep consistency?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the hardest thing in computer science, naming things, is also one if the most important one. A reader/client of your code should understand what the method do just by looking at its signature. If he needs to read the method's body too in order to understand what it does then you've failed.

So, if somehow, by some team rules, or something else,  you can understand that a particular method is a getter without using the "get" prefix then don't use it, otherwise use it because we, the other ones, expect to see a "get" in front of a getter.

P.S. this is orthogonal to DDD.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pure and simple Object Oriented question. Methods must be named from the perspective of the objects that receives messages and not from the perspective of the objects that send the messages.
The "get" prefix fits the second case.

Answer (score 1):

To me this is something that just who want to lose time in unuseful conversations care about.

- Is the domain concept understandable with the `get` prefix?
- Do you need the prefix for something?

If you want to do a domain model with hibernate, you HAVE to do the `setXXX` and `getXXX` methods, because it use the JavaBean standard.

The main point here is that the `setXXX()` can be dangerous if exposed, because you can skip the consistency controls that you should implement in the `doTheDomainAction()` method, so if you need them maybe put them as `private` is a safer choice (or `protected` if `private` is not suitable).

About the `getXXX` methods, I think that if they are just for read immutable values there is no problem in having them, the only thing you need to care is that they explicitate the domain concept and whoever will use them can't have a misunderstanding of what they are.

Comment: It seems that it's not mandatory to follow the JavaBean standard with Hibernate about that. It is just recommended, the documentation states: _"Although Hibernate does not require it, it is recommended to follow the JavaBean conventions and define getters and setters for entity persistent attributes."_.  
Anyway, I get your point: there are more benefits to keep the prefix as it's still understandable for everyone and it preserves the compatibility with tools that would require it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Skimming through the repo, I'm not sure it can be called a reference. Besides, you should look at DDD sample projects as inspiration, not models to replicate.

How the getter/setters are named is an **unimportant technical detail** and **the last thing you should try to emulate** when looking at DDD sample code. It has nothing to do with DDD. As far as naming, go with your own style of OO (or whatever paradigm) **as long as names reflect your domain's Ubiquitous Language**.

Comment: I wrote "seems to be" a reference as it is made by Eric Evans's company [Domain Language](http://www.domainlanguage.com/) and [Citerus](http://www.citerus.se/). Every detail in naming should not be considered lightly. I suspected a reason if it was not prefixed. The quote of [VoiceOfUnreason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54734/) from Vaughn Vernon explain it.

Comment: Vaughn Vernon's quote leaves unexplained why getters outside the Domain package were prefixed in that particular code base -- you precisely wrote a comment about that just below @VoiceofUnreason's answer.

Comment: If you expect to get something useful out of a DDD sample code base and are looking at details like accessor prefixes, you're looking at it the wrong way.

Comment: What made me on this way is that I thought if there was something that would break the javabean standard, the reason could be important or interesting to know. Yes the question remains about the getters outside the domain package. But now, I understand that the prefix is not an important detail. Then we can keep it in the model as it's still reflecting the ubiquitous language. Thanks.